# Independence of two functions of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If X and Y are two independent geometric random variables with parameters p and q find the joint pmf of M= max(X,Y) and D= X-Y?

I'm wondering intuitively are M and D independent? I solved this problem and found the marginals but I got that they are not independent but I'm trying to figure out why conceptually. Or did I make a mistake and are they actually independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\max(X, Y) = m$ for some integer $m$. Then
$$
1 \leq X, Y \leq m
$$
Therefore,
$$
1 - m\leq D = X - Y \leq m -1
$$
in which $D$ can take each value in $[1 - m, m - 1]$ with non-zero probability. As you can see, when $m$ changes, the distribution of $D$ also changes. Therefore, $D$ should be dependent on $M$.

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that in both cases the geometric distribution stands for the number of trials needed to reach a first success (so $X,Y\geq1$)

Observe that:

$$\Pr(D=1\mid M=1)=0\neq\Pr(D=1\mid M=2)$$
This indicates that $M$ and $D$ are not independent.